# NSIS silent installer - jump not observed

Tags: installation, nsis, silent, silent-installer

I am trying NSIS doc example for silent installer, [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/silent.nsi). Uncommenting the line

```
; SilentInstall silent
```

then yes, my installer is silent. However, it displays message boxes. It is expected that message boxes do appear even if installer is silent. To make message boxes silent as well, one has to play with /SD option for each message box. The example script proposes it here:

```
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "This is not a silent installer" /SD IDOK
```

Another mean to make the message box silent is exposed: it checks if silent. If silent, then jump two lines ahead (so do not show message box)

```
IfSilent 0 +2
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION 'This is a "silent" installer'
```

This second solution does not work for me. If i set the installer silent, the box with 'this is a silent installer' does appear. If i change it for

```
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION 'This is a "silent" installer' /SD IDOK
```

the message does not appear.

Why is the jump in

```
IfSilent 0 +2
```

not working? `+3`is not making it either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the first argument is offset to jump *in case of silent installation* (the second one for non-silent).

Try this:

```
IfSilent +2 0
```

Comment: if silent then jump over the next two instructions, else 0. is that right? what does this mean, else ) ? thanks !

Comment: Yes. To be more precise: if silent mode jump to the instruction after the `MessageBox`, so only one instruction (`MessageBox`) is skipped. Offset 0 means current line, +1 means immediately following line and so on. So +2 means the line you have immediately after the `MessageBox` (and this is to be executed).

Comment: and 0 means 'if not silent, do not jump, just keep at current line', is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The second argument is optional so in this case it could be only `IfSilent +2`. You can take a look at *4.9.4.12 IfSilent* here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html

Answer (score 8):

Like zbynour said, you got the parameters mixed up.

To avoid issues with relative jumps, use the logiclib:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

...

${IfNot} ${Silent}
  MessageBox ...
${EndIf}
```